# How can I reset ATI GPU's to factory settings on Xubuntu?

Tags: amd-radeon, xubuntu, factory-defaults

These cards have been severely overclocked and now I want to just reset to whatever settings the factory used.

How can I do that via Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the cards seemed to do the trick.